# Java NativeMemoryTracking flag and utility commands Azul JDK

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, azul-zulu, azul-zing

we have recently moved to Azul jdk instead of using Oracle.
it seems there is a missing of documentation regarding profiling flags and their usage.

for example, if i want to track native memory in Oracle i just add this flag:

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[detail|summary]
```

and when i want to get the statistics i just use the jcmd as follows:

```
jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory
```

i am trying to perform the same with the Azul jdk unsuccessfully.
there is a lack of documentation on their site:
https://docs.azul.com/zing/ZingNMT.htm

they are just specifying the flags i need to add with no usage examples at all.
is anybody ever used jcmd/jmap/jstat  or any Oracle HotSpot utility commands with the Azul jdk?
is it even exists or are there any alternatives? it's unclear from their site.

Comment: The documentation you linked refers to Azul Zing, while in your question you seem to talk about Azul OpenJDK builds. They are two different things. Which one are you using? Make sure to use the `jcmd` distributed with the software you are using.

Comment: you are right, actually I am using Azul OpenJDK Zulu. but it's just does not matter. there is no proper documentation for this neither. am I suppose to guess which utility commands it supports or how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Azul Zulu is an OpenJDK build, just like Oracle Java, meaning they are exactly like OpenJDK. There is no difference in functionality between them, meaning what you can do with one you can do with others.